# Why does Xcode save my files in autosave information?

Tags: macos, xcode, autosave

I ran into this problem today while writing code. Whenever I open a source file in Xcode, make changes and save them, the file will be copied to the "autosave information" folder and the references in the source tree view (command + 1) are changed to the new location.

Right now I cannot edit files "in place" but have to edit them and copy them back from "autosave information".

The code files are in a folder within "Shared" (my local "GitHub" repository folder to be exact). The account I'm using to edit the files owns them and has r/w-permissions. 
On another account which doesn't own the files but has r/w-permissions the problem doesn't occur.

My Mac is a MacBook Pro Retina 15" 2014, 2,2 Ghz i7 running OS X 10.10.5. Does anybody have an idea what's wrong and how to fix it?

---

**UPDATE**

So, I found out two things

1. it happens with files outside of the "GitHub" folder in "Shared" as well
2. it only happens if I open a window in XCode and add files (the file I open first is saved in place, the added files are saved in "Autosave Information")

Removing ACL permissions didn't help.

Comment: what are the permissions including ACL on the directory? and why in Shared - git is used to share things but each user has their own copy

Comment: The permissions for the GitHub folder are `drwxrwxrwt  7 development  wheel  238  6 Okt 13:47 GitHub` the ACL for the GitHub folder is  `0: group:everyone allow list,add_file,search,delete,add_subdirectory,file_inherit,directory_inherit
` ("development" is the name of the account I use for development). I don't see why putting GitHub in Shared would be a bad idea. Is it?

Comment: GitHub is the server - got is the tool that you are using and the design is each user has there own checkout so you can see who does what - it is not designed for sharing the checkout so could have issues

Comment: @Mark I've been running this set-up for some time now and I never had a problem. So, I think it's unrelated to GitHub.

Comment: Yes it is nothing to do with Github that is the server and no part of github is on  your machine

Comment: That's not true (there are hidden `.git` folders on the machine which contain the change database the changes are mirrored online however). I also do not know what this would have to do with my question.

Comment: got and github are different things, ir look at got manuals not Github (GitHub is just a git server) - also what do you mean by it happens with files outside of the "GitHub" folder in "Shared"

Comment: I meant this happens with files outside of the "GitHub" as well. In other words the behavior is not restricted to the "GitHub" folder. Edited my post to clarify this, thanks.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have the exact same problem and it's driving me nuts. I'm sure it's "user error"... millions of Xcode developers do things differently than I do. "When I edit a file and save it, I intend to overwrite the original" seems like a reasonable default behavior.

Comment: Sorry, I did not. :( My takeaway was to not put a Git repository anywhere inside `/Users/Shared`.